# WCF streaming w/message contract returning byte array

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0, streaming

I've searched for an answer and haven't found anything. I assume I'm missing something simple, but I can't tell what it is.

I've added a method to one of our WCF services that is supposed to return a stream as part of the message contract. However, when I add the service reference on the client side, the stream  portion of the message contract is a byte array, not a stream. I've added essentially the same method without the message contract (which won't be an option), and that one is a stream on the client side.

### Service contract

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "FileService", Namespace = "http://services.mycompanycom/Data/")]
public interface IFileService : IServiceBase
{
    [OperationContract( IsOneWay = false )]
    [FaultContract( typeof( ServiceException ), Name = "ServiceException", Namespace = "http://services.mycompanycom/Common/" )]
    FileStreamResponse GetFileStream( FileIDMessage message );

    [OperationContract( IsOneWay = false )]
    [FaultContract( typeof( ServiceException ), Name = "ServiceException", Namespace = "http://services.mycompanycom/Common/" )]
    Stream GetFileStream2( AuthTicket ticket, int FileID );
}
```

### Message contract

```
[MessageContract]
public sealed class FileStreamResponse {
    [MessageHeader( MustUnderstand = true )]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [MessageHeader( MustUnderstand = true )]
    public bool IsZip { get; set; }
    [MessageHeader( MustUnderstand = true )]
    public long Length { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember( Order = 1 )]
    public Stream FileByteStream;
}
```

### Service code

This gets configured on the client side as a returning a byte array:

```
[FaultContract( typeof( ServiceException ), Name = "ServiceException", Namespace = "http://services.mycompanycom/Common/" )]
public FileStreamResponse GetFileStream( FileIDMessage message ) {
    CheckRights( message.AuthTicket, message.FileID, EntityEnum.Blob );

    var blob = new BlobBroker( ).GetByPk( message.GetSecurityTicket( ), message.FileID );
    if( blob.PkBlob == 0 || blob.BlobData == null )
        throw ServiceUtilities.LogError( "File record not found.", "File record not found.", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod( ) );
    var response = new FileStreamResponse {
                                              FileName = blob.FileName,
                                              IsZip = blob.IsZip,
                                              Length = blob.BlobData.Length,
                                              FileByteStream = new MemoryStream( blob.BlobData )
                                          };
    response.FileByteStream.Position = 0;
    return response;
}
```

This gets configured on the client side as a stream:

```
[FaultContract( typeof( ServiceException ), Name = "ServiceException", Namespace = "http://services.mycompanycom/Common/" )]
public Stream GetFileStream2( AuthTicket ticket, int FileID ) {
    var f = new FileIDMessage {
                                  FileID = FileID,
                                  AuthTicket = ticket
                              };
    return this.GetFileStream( f ).FileByteStream;
}
```

### Server config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="BasicServiceBehavior" name="MyCompany.Web.MyServices.FileService">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="secureEndpointBehavior"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamingBinding"
                contract="MyCompany.Web.MyServices.IFileService" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="StreamingBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedResponse"
                 textEncoding="utf-8">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                     maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBindingWithCrossDomain"/>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="secureEndpointBehavior" >
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
                <authorizationInspector /> 
                <operationLogger />
                <wsdlExtras location="http://localservices.mycompany.com/" exportXmlComments="false" singleFile="false" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="BasicServiceBehavior">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                <!-- need to update in build script -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <secureMetadata locationUrl="http://localservices.mycompany.com/" />
                <exceptionHandler />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

### Client-side generated code

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18033")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://services.mycompany.com/Data/")]
public partial class FileStreamResponse : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private byte[] fileByteStreamField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary", Order=0)]
    public byte[] FileByteStream {
        get {
            return this.fileByteStreamField;
        }
        set {
            this.fileByteStreamField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("FileByteStream");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class FileStreamResponse1 {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://services.mycompany.com/Data/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string FileName;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://services.mycompany.com/Data/")]
    public bool IsZip;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://services.mycompany.com/Data/")]
    public long Length;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://services.mycompany.com/Data/", Order=0)]
    public ServiceTest.MyCompanyServices.FileStreamResponse FileStreamResponse;

    public FileStreamResponse1() {
    }

    public FileStreamResponse1(string FileName, bool IsZip, long Length, ServiceTest.MyCompanyServices.FileStreamResponse FileStreamResponse) {
        this.FileName = FileName;
        this.IsZip = IsZip;
        this.Length = Length;
        this.FileStreamResponse = FileStreamResponse;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetFileStream2Response", WrapperNamespace="http://services.mycompany.com/Data/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetFileStream2Response {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://services.mycompany.com/Data/", Order=0)]
    public System.IO.Stream GetFileStream2Result;

    public GetFileStream2Response() {
    }

    public GetFileStream2Response(System.IO.Stream GetFileStream2Result) {
        this.GetFileStream2Result = GetFileStream2Result;
    }
}
```

### Client test code

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        var svc = new FileServiceClient( );
        Console.WriteLine( "Logging in..." );
        var ticket = svc.Logon( "userid", "password" );
        Console.WriteLine( "Calling service..." );
        FileStreamResponse fsr;
        bool isZip;
        long size;
        string filename = svc.GetFileStream( ticket, 51575, out isZip, out size, out fsr );
        if( fsr != null && fsr.FileByteStream != null ) { // fsr.FileByteStream is byte[]
            Console.WriteLine( "Filename: {0}", filename );
            Console.WriteLine( "Zip: {0}", isZip );
            Console.WriteLine( "Length: {0}", size );
            Console.WriteLine( "Saving file..." );
            using( var fs = new FileStream( Path.Combine( @"c:\temp", filename ), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write ) ) {
                const int bufferSize = 65536;
                var buffer = new byte[ bufferSize ];
                //var bytesRead = response.FileStreamResponse.FileByteStream.
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "Press ENTER to exit." );
        Console.ReadLine( );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the client code, and the generated client proxy code for each case.  Are you using svcutil or similar? if so, what options are you using to generate the client proxy?

Comment: The generated code is now there. All attempts have been through VS2012 Add Service Reference. This time I just accepted the defaults, though I've played with checking/unchecking Allow generating of asynchronous operations and Always generate message contracts.

Comment: I would highly recommend you use svcutil or wscfblue instead of VS

Comment: Strange... in the generated client proxy, I wonder if the PropertyChanged event variable is causing an issue.  Since the stream must be the one and only parameter in the message contract...

Comment: I regenerated it using svcutil (no options other than namespace) and, while it didn't add the INotifyPropertyChanged code, it still generated the property as a byte array instead of a stream. However, when I look at the wsdl generated by ?singleWsdl, both are listed as StreamBody types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is the problem (not part of the code above, but the class that is passed to the GetFileStream method):

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class FileIDMessage : SecureMessageBase
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int FileID;
}
```

If I remove the (IsWrapped = false), it returns a stream instead of a byte array.

Comment: I'm currently running into (almost) the same problem, but I'm not in the position to remove the IsWrapped = false flag. Is there any other way to overcome this problem?

Comment: No, sorry. That's the only solution I found. That said, once I found that, I stopped looking.